# Logical Operators doesn't work in javascript and about node counts by input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make node counter by id, node name, and attribute name&value!

Here I would like to check if every  is empty then show "HERE IS NO VALUE OF YOU ENTERED".

here in the end of  I try to use <&&> but it doesn't work!
 also is that impossible to use just  tag instead of  in the end of the code? when i tried, it show eror :(

** I have no idea of how to count attribute name&value number..**
I'm realy begginer of javascript ! thank you in advance guys!!

this is my form html.

```js
function javascript_click() {
  /* 자바스크립트 id값 찾기 */
  if (document.getElementById("value1").value) {
    var val = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    if (document.getElementById(val)) {
      //var myNodelist = document.getElementById("val").value;
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신아이디는 " + val + " 이며 id갯수는 1개입니다.By javascript <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  }
  /* 자바스크립트 노드명 찾기 */
  else if (document.getElementById("value2").value) {
    var val2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
    if (document.querySelector(val2)) {
      // alert(val2);
      var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll(val2);
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신 노드는 " + val2 + " 이며 노드갯수는 " + myNodelist.length + "개 입니다. By javascript<br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  }
  /* 자바스크립트  attribute 찾기 */
  /* 자바스크립트 속성명&값  찾기 */
  else if (
    document.getElementById("value3").value &&
    document.getElementById("value4").value
  ) {
    var val2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
    if (document.querySelector(val2)) {
      // alert(val2);
      var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll(val2);
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신 노드는 " + val2 + " 이며 노드갯수는 " + myNodelist.length + "개 입니다. By javascript<br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  } else if (
    (document.getElementById("value1").value &&
    document.getElementById("value2").value &&
    document.getElementById("value3").value &&
    document.getElementById("value4").value) == 0
  ) {
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "THERE IS NO VALUE OF YOU ENTERED<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table class="tg" id="tg">
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>node name</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cnt"></div>
</form>
<div class="button">
  <button id='btn_javascript' onclick="javascript_click();">자바스크립트</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try and explain in simple english, what you are trying to achieve? If language is a barrier, try using example: like *when id:'', name: ''...* do this. *when .....*

Comment: I want to check every <input type="text"> and all that is empty then show "THERE IS NO VALUE OF YOU ENTERED<br>"

Comment: @cat_lover if I understand correct, you want to check and tell if some value is missing. So if I have: `id: 'bla', name: '', attr1: 'bla', attr2: 'bla2'`, you need error message, *Missing Node Name*. Am i correct?

Comment: there are 4 input tags! if all input tags is empty then i want to show error message!  i mean when user didn't put values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do validation like this:

```
  if (document.getElementById("value1").value!=='') {
    let val1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신아이디는 " + val1 + " 이며 id갯수는 1개입니다.By javascript <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
```